# How should I go about doing a real time chat between users in PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm developing an application using PhoneGap. I'm using PHP and MySQL as the backend and jQuery mobile on the frontend.

I want a message board where users can do real time chatting.

What is the best way to go about this, so that it will work in all platforms once I deploy? I just need a good advice on how I should go forward for developing such an application.

Answer (score 3):

Google is always your friend:

http://quickblox.com/developers/XMPP_Chat_Phonegap_Sample

http://phonegaptutorial.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/html5-tutorial-html5-tutorial-two-chat.html